# How do I connect Kubernetes Engine on GCP to an external Google Cloud Storage Bucket?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

I have deployed a pod on a Kubernetes Cluster on GCP. I have used a Persistent volume using a PVC as the volume mount.
I need to input data(.doc files) residing in Google Cloud Storage buckets into the the pod's data path.

How do I mount this external storage or injest the data into the pod?

And I require this this to be a live connection or for the injestion to happen at regular intervals.

Comment: I am confused. You can't currently mount GCS buckets as PV/PVCs. What are you trying to do –can you simplify your question?

Comment: Yes, I want to mount a GCS bucket as a PV/PVC.

Comment: you can't do it

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to mount google cloud storage buckets into Kubernetes-
GCS Fuse has to be built into the image and then the cloud storage buckets can be mounted as directories. I referred to these links to implement this-

https://karlstoney.com/2017/03/01/fuse-mount-in-kubernetes/

https://github.com/maciekrb/gcs-fuse-sample

Comment: Don't know why the down votes, this was exactly the solution I was looking (to have filesystem access to a bucket from a container), thanks a lot!

Comment: Even I'm not sure why the down votes. This solution  perfectly answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Ahmet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54929/ahmet-alp-balkan-google) and [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9231144/patrick-w), it is not possible to mount Google Cloud Storage (GCS) buckets as PV/PVCs at Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE).